# FCKeditor in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, fckeditor

I have a website online, It works without any problem. I downloaded it;s files and tried to run by VS 2017 But it doesnt work The errors are

'FredCK.FCKeditorV2.FCKeditor' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'FredCK.FCKeditorV2.FCKeditor' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and     The type or namespace name 'Zip' does not exist in the namespace 'BuilderClasses' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I change the FCKeditor dll but no changes. Could you please help me?

Comment: nuget packages missing?

Comment: No, I add all of them to the project

Comment: If it helps my website is asp.net 2.2

Comment: and another thing: I use publish!!!

Comment: It seems you are using a very old version (they dropped the `F` from the name a long time ago). Have you tried a newer version from their [website](https://ckeditor.com/)?

Comment: It was because of inheritance! I remove the inherit line and it works now. Thank you